# Transient NSPopover swallows first click on parent window control

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa

I have a transient NSPopover and when it's open and I click a button in the parent window the popover is dismissed instead and the click "swallowed". Only the second click on the button triggers the action properly.

Is there a way to pass the first click through to the control directly and dismiss the popover in one step?

Answer (score 1):

NSPopover does seem to swallow the event for the targeted position view. Other views are fine. My solution is to get the delegate to forward the last mouse down event to the target view if hit testing reveals it was the clicked view. Unfortunatety NSApp -currentEvent is nil when the delegate gets messaged - not sure why. So I added an event monitor to the app delegate like so:

```
- (void)addEventMonitor 
{ 
    if (self.eventMonitor) {
        return;
    }

    self.eventMonitor = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSLeftMouseDownMask) handler:^(NSEvent *incomingEvent) {
    NSEvent *result = incomingEvent;
    self.monitoredEvent = result;
    return result;
    }];
```

}

When the delegate closes it checks to see it the last monitored event was in the target:

```
- (void)popoverDidClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // [NSApp currentEvent] is nil here
    NSEvent *event = [(BPApplicationDelegate *)[NSApp delegate] monitoredEvent];
    if (event && (event.type & NSLeftMouseDown)) {
        NSPoint pt = [self.targetView.superview convertPoint:event.locationInWindow fromView:nil];
        if ([self.TargetView hitTest:pt]) {
            [NSApp postEvent:event atStart:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Querying the event in `popoverDidClose:` is too late, the delegate method you should query the event in is `popoverWillClose:`. The window still has the mouse-down event at that time.